# Implementing variadic type traits

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, template-meta-programming, generative-programming

### Intro

I'm looking for **a pattern** to convert C++ type traits into their **variadic counterparts**. A **methodology** to approach the problem would be appreciated and **generative programming** patterns to automate the task would be ideal.

### Example

Take the following :

```
std::is_same<T, U>::value;
```

I want to write a trait that works like so :

```
std::are_same<T1, T2, T3, T4>::value;
```

---

### Current approach

It's pretty [**straightforward**](http://ideone.com/QZk600) to implement the `are_same`; **Seeking a general solution** we can come up with a tool for any variadic trait implementing **universal quantification** :

```
template<template<class,class> class F, typename...Ts>
struct Univ;

template<template<class, class> class F, typename T, typename U, typename...Ts>
struct Univ<F, T, U, Ts...>
{
    static const int value = F<T, U>::value && Univ<F, U, Ts...>::value;
};

template<template<class, class> class F, typename T>
struct Univ<F, T>
{
    static const int value = 1;
};
```

so that eg `are_same` could be [**written as**](http://ideone.com/fSv8GL)

```
Univ<is_same,int, int, int>::value
```

and this could apply when creating traits like `are_classes`, `are_scalars` etc

### Generalizing

Minor tweaks could give **existential quantification** out of the previous snippet (replacing `&&` with `||`) so that we create traits like `exist_same` in the following fashion :

```
Exist<is_same, int, double, float>::value
```

### Question

The previous cover generalization on [type traits](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/type_traits) related to

- Primary type categories
- Composite type categories
- Type properties
- Supported operations

**How would I generalize for type traits** like the following :

```
    enable_if -> enable_if_any // enable if any clause is true
                 enable_if_all // enalbe if all clauses are true
                 enable_for    // enable only for the type provided
```

**The `exist_same`** example above is oversimplified. Any ideas for a correct implementation?

**There are type_traits** that "return" modified types. Any suggestion for scaling those to implementations for arbitrary number of types ?

**Are there type_traits** which are made **not to scale to arbitrary number of type arguments** ?

Comment: For the "returning multiple types": You can only return one top-level type. To return a list of types, one usually uses `std::tuple< T1, T2, ... >`.

Comment: Stuff like this makes me want the `template` equivalent of `using` -- `template<template<class,class>class F>using for_all=template<class...Ts>Univ<F,Ts...>;`, used like `for_all<std::is_same><int,int,int>`, and it would let you easily pass the `template<class...>` generated to other meta programming without ugliness.

Comment: Univ is a very useful tool. I wonder if you could supply the implementation of `Exist`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I don't fully understand what exactly you'd like to achieve, but the following helpers might be useful, starting with `bool_sequence`:

```
#include <type_traits>

// Note: std::integer_sequence is C++14,
// but it's easy to use your own version (even stripped down)
// for the following purpose:
template< bool... Bs >
using bool_sequence = std::integer_sequence< bool, Bs... >;

// Alternatively, not using C++14:
template< bool... > struct bool_sequence {};
```

next, you can check if all or any boolean value or set with these:

```
template< bool... Bs >
using bool_and = std::is_same< bool_sequence< Bs... >,
                               bool_sequence< ( Bs || true )... > >;

template< bool... Bs >
using bool_or = std::integral_constant< bool, !bool_and< !Bs... >::value >;
```

they come in handy as building blocks for more advanced and specialized traits. For example, you could use them like this:

```
typename< typename R, bool... Bs > // note: R first, no default :(
using enable_if_any = std::enable_if< bool_or< Bs... >::value, R >;

typename< typename R, bool... Bs > // note: R first, no default :(
using enable_if_all = std::enable_if< bool_and< Bs... >::value, R >;

typename< typename T, typename... Ts >
using are_same = bool_and< std::is_same< T, Ts >::value... >;
```

Comment: @0x499602D2 Boolean logic: `bool_or<B1,B2,B3,...>` = `!bool_and<!B1,!B2,!B3,!...>` - does that answer your question? Otherwise, please be more specific which part of the implementation is causing you trouble.

Comment: +1 `bool_sequence< ( Bs || true )... >` is a most handy snippet.

Comment: @Solkar I'd be tempted by `(Bs,true)...`.   Regardless, I like that it has constant recursive depth!

Comment: @Yakk `(Bs,true)...` will lead to warnings on some compilers, that's why I used `(Bs||true)...`.

Comment: Funny looks like bool_or<false>::value reports true in VC++ 2013.  Works in clang

Comment: Isn't this missing some of the bool_sequence implementation for C++11 (pre-C++14)?

Comment: @einpoklum I don't understand your question. What do you think is missing exactly?

Comment: @DanielFrey: It seems like `bool_sequence` is never anything other than `{ }` the way you defined it (right after `// Alternatively, not using C++14`).

Comment: @einpoklum Yes. For the above example that is all that is needed. This is a SO answer, not a complete implementation of an STL.

Comment: @DanielFrey: Oh, you mean the different template parameters would be enough to make `bool_sequence<false>` not the same as `bool_sequence<true>`?

Comment: @einpoklum Exactly. It's a template, each set of (different) parameters generates a different type and that is what is needed for `std::is_same`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [`std::conditional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional) in order to achieve `enable_if_all` and `enable_if_any`:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <string>

namespace detail
{
template <typename... Conds>
struct and_ : std::true_type {};

template <typename... Conds>
struct or_ : std::false_type {};

template <typename Cond, typename... Conds>
struct and_<Cond, Conds...>
    : std::conditional<Cond::value, detail::and_<Conds...>, std::false_type>::type {};

template <typename Cond, typename... Conds>
struct or_<Cond, Conds...>
    : std::conditional<Cond::value, std::true_type, detail::and_<Conds...>>::type {};
}

template <typename... T>
using are_all_pod = detail::and_<std::is_pod<T>...>;

template <typename... T>
using any_is_pod = detail::or_<std::is_pod<T>...>;

template <typename... Args, typename = typename std::enable_if<are_all_pod<Args...>::value>::type>
void f(Args... args)
{
  (void)std::initializer_list<int>{(std::cout << args << '\n' , 0)...};
}

template <typename... Args, typename = typename std::enable_if<any_is_pod<Args...>::value>::type>
void g(Args... args)
{
  (void)std::initializer_list<int>{(std::cout << args << '\n' , 0)...};
}

int main()
{
  std::string s = "hello";  // non pod
  //f(1, 1.2, s); // this will fail because not all types are pod
  g(1, 1.2, s);   // this compiles because there is at least one pod in argument pack 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by the excellent idea in Daniel Fray's answer, we can even extend the scope of these *variadic traits*. Using tuples, we can apply traits on collections of variadic type packs instead of "only" comparing a variadic pack of types to a reference type.

For example, we will be able to see if the types `int, int, int, float` are the same types as `int, int, int, float` (indeed they are!).

To do so, we need the following constructs:

- Tuples and a way to produce the tail of a tuple
- A way to extend bool sequences by appending (or prepending) boolean values to it

### TL;DR

I compiled a few examples in this <kbd>[live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dd3842e751179867)</kbd>.

### Defining the variadic trait facilities

First we provide a helper to extend a bool sequence one value at a time:

```
template <bool ... Bs>
struct bool_sequence {};

template <bool b, typename T>
struct prepend_bool_seq;

template <bool b, bool ... bs>
struct prepend_bool_seq<b, bool_sequence<bs...>> {
    typedef bool_sequence<b, bs...> type;
};
```

Now some logic on bool sequences (taken from other answers)

```
template <typename T>
struct all_of;

template <bool ... Bs>
struct all_of<bool_sequence<Bs...>> :
    public std::is_same<bool_sequence<true, Bs...>, bool_sequence<Bs..., true>> {};

template <typename T>
struct any_of;

template <bool ... Bs>
struct any_of<bool_sequence<Bs...>> :
    public std::integral_constant<bool, !all_of<bool_sequence<!Bs...>>::value> {};
```

Then, we define an helper template to access a tuple's tail:

```
namespace details {

// Sentinel type to detect empty tuple tails
struct null_type {};

template <typename T>
struct tuple_tail;

template <typename T>
struct tuple_tail<std::tuple<T>> {
    typedef null_type type;
};

template <typename T, typename ... Ts>
struct tuple_tail<std::tuple<T, Ts...>> {
    typedef std::tuple<Ts...> type;
};

}
```

---

### Combining the constructs

With these bricks, we can now define an `apply_trait` template to apply a given type trait on several type lists:

```
namespace details {

template <template <typename...> class Trait, typename ... Tuples>
struct apply_trait {
    static constexpr bool atomic_value =
                     Trait<typename std::tuple_element<0u, Tuples>::type...>::value;
    typedef typename prepend_bool_seq<atomic_value,
                     typename apply_trait<Trait,
                     typename tuple_tail<Tuples>::type...>::type>::type type;
};

template <template <typename...> class Trait, typename ... Tuples>
struct apply_trait<Trait, null_type, Tuples...> {
    typedef bool_sequence<> type;
};

}
```

This template recursively computes the bool sequence given by the trait application in a bottom-up fashion. Now, provided with the resulting bool sequence, we can perform logical operations on the result with the helpers defined above.

Next, some helpers can reproduce the logic of your `are_same` example for any binary (or unary) type trait:

```
// Helper templates for common type traits (unary and binary)
template <template <typename> class UnaryTrait, typename ... Ts>
using apply_unary_trait = details::apply_trait<UnaryTrait, std::tuple<Ts...>>;

template <template <typename, typename> class BinaryTrait, typename Ref, typename ... Ts>
using apply_binary_trait = details::apply_trait<BinaryTrait,
                                                std::tuple<decltype(std::declval<Ts>(), std::declval<Ref>())...>,
                                                std::tuple<Ts...>>;

template <template <typename, typename> class BinaryTrait, typename Ref, typename ... Ts>
using apply_binary_trait_ref_last = details::apply_trait<BinaryTrait,
                                             std::tuple<Ts...>,
                                             std::tuple<decltype(std::declval<Ts>(), std::declval<Ref>())...>>;
```

For example, we can reproduce the `are_same` design you brought up for every binary trait:

```
template <typename Ref, typename ... Ts>
using are_same = all_of<typename apply_binary_trait<std::is_same, Ref, Ts...>::type>;
```

We can also apply the traits logic on lists. For example, given two lists of types, we may want to check if a type in the first list is convertible to its matching type in the second list:

```
// int is convertible to long and char const* is convertible to std::string
std::cout << all_of<details::apply_trait<std::is_convertible,
                                         std::tuple<int, char const*>,
                                         std::tuple<long, std::string>::type>::value;
```