# Understanding why compile-time boolean algebra doesn't work

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, template-meta-programming

I am trying to implement a basic template metaprogramming struct which determines if a list of types are all the same using `std::is_same`. I tried to implement it as follows:

```
template <typename T, typename U, typename... Args>
struct check_same {
     static const bool value = std::is_same<T, U>::value && check_same<U, Args...>::value;
};

template <typename T, typename U>
struct check_same {
     static const bool value = std::is_same<T, U>::value;
};
```

However, if I try to instantiate `check_same` I get the following compiler error:

> 'check_same' : too few template arguments

Why is this not a valid way to perform compile-time boolean algebra? Surely as all of the expressions involved are `constexpr` (or `const` here as MSVC doesn't yet implement `constexpr`), it should compile?

---

The following will fail to compile:

```
int main() 
{
    static_assert( check_same<int, unsigned int, float>::value, "Types must be the same" );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're missing a type for `value`. Not sure what that has to do with your error.

Comment: [See this answer for a great `are_same` implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24687161/701092)

Comment: "too few template arguments" because Args are consumed down to 0 by this recursion, and no check_same<> has less than 2 mandatory parameters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Class templates in C++ cannot be "overloaded" like functions. You cannot redeclare the same template again and again with a different set of parameters and expect it to compile. For example, this will not compile

```
template <typename A> struct S {};
template <typename A, typename B> struct S {};
```

It will not compile because it attempts to declare template class `S` twice. This is illegal.

Your code suffers from exactly the same error: you have declared template `check_same` twice. You can't do that.

The technique you are apparently attempting to use should be based on template *specialization*, not on a template redeclaration. You have to declare your *primary* template only once

```
template <typename T, typename U, typename... Args>
struct check_same {
     static const bool value = std::is_same<T, U>::value && check_same<U, Args...>::value;
};
```

and then provide a *partial specialization* of that primary template for a specific, more restricted set of arguments

```
template <typename T, typename U>
struct check_same<T, U> {
     static const bool value = std::is_same<T, U>::value;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
template <typename T, typename... Args>
struct check_same: std::true_type {};

template <typename T, typename U, typename...Args>
struct check_same<T,U,Args...>: std::integral_constant<bool,
  std::is_same<T,U>::value && check_same<U, Args...>::value
> {};
```

the first one only evaluates when there is exactly one argument.  The second specialization catches 2 or more.

It errors if you pass 0 arguments.  I'd argue that you should handle that as well:

```
template <typename... Args>
struct check_same: std::true_type {};

template <typename T, typename U, typename...Args>
struct check_same<T,U,Args...>: std::integral_constant<bool,
  std::is_same<T,U>::value && check_same<U, Args...>::value
> {};
```

which actually takes no more specializations, as the first works for both 0 and 1 argument.

Comment: @dyp how does that reduce number of instantiations?  You get 3 types instantiated per recursion, same as me?

Comment: It's some kind of short-circuiting: the recursion ends when one check returns `false` and the remaining checks are not performed. However you get one more instantiation per step due to the `conditional`, so it's probably not worth it.

Comment: @dyp both branches of conditional are fully evaluated, so the checks are performed, just discarded.  To pull off a short-circuit, you need to do more work than `conditional`.

Comment: +1 for using `std::integral_constant` for this. loc are too precious to waste them, aren't they.

Comment: Huh? Why should the branch which is not used require an instantiation? http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2c7146fd7e7c8dfe

Comment: @dyp The full type of the `std::conditional` instance must be instantiated, which is `std::conditional< false, LHS, RHS >`.  Both `LHS` and `RHS` must be full types, which means any `template` expressions get fully instantiated on both branches.  In order to avoid this, you need `typename my_lazy_conditional< false, LHS_template, RHS_template >::template apply< pack< LHS_args >, pack< RHS_args > >::type` or something like it.

Comment: Why do `LHS` and `RHS` have to be full types? IIRC, implicit instantiations are required only if a completely-defined object type is *required*, I don't see why `conditional` should require that. You can even use incomplete types: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/62a5bbadd53779d3