# Check a parameter pack for all of type T

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

Jonathan Wakely's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29603857/3098505) to the question [Type trait to check that all types in a parameter pack are copy constructible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29603364/type-trait-to-check-that-all-types-in-a-parameter-pack-are-copy-constructible/29603857#29603857) gives a simple(ish) way to check if all of the variables expanded in a parameter pack are of the same type - eg:

```
#include <type_traits>

namespace detail {
    enum class enabler {};
}

template <bool Condition>
using EnableIf =
    typename std::enable_if<Condition, detail::enabler>::type;

template<typename... Conds>
struct and_ : std::true_type {};

template<typename Cond, typename... Conds>
struct and_<Cond, Conds...>
        : std::conditional<Cond::value, and_<Conds...>,
        std::false_type>::type {};

template<typename... T>
using areInts = and_<std::is_same<T,int>...>;

template<typename... T>
using areMySpecificClass = and_<std::is_same<T,MySpecificClass>...>;
```

I can't work out how to extend this, to write a template like `areTypeT`, for example.

My first attempts stumbled on "Parameter pack 'T' must be at the end of the template parameter list". My more recent attempt compiles, but if I use it then I get substitution failures:

```
template<typename Target>
template<typename... T1>
using areT = and_<std::is_same<T1,Target>...>;
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: For a `concept` based solution, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61483494/2085626

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your syntax is just off a bit, you don't need two separate template declarations, that syntax is for defining member templates out-of-class:

```
template<typename Target, typename... Ts>
using areT = and_<std::is_same<Ts,Target>...>;

static_assert(areT<int,int,int,int>::value,"wat");
static_assert(!areT<int,float,int,int>::value,"wat");
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/42f04bd871145686)</kbd>

Answer (score 13):

C++17 defines a version of `and_` called `std::conjunction` defined in the `<type_traits>` header from the standard library.

```
template <typename T, typename ...Ts>
using areT = std::conjunction<std::is_same<T,Ts>...>;

static_assert(areT<int,int,int,int>::value);
```

There is also a version of `std::conjunction` called `std::conjunction_v` which provides the `value` data member of its instantiation. So too you could define an `areT_v` C++14 variable template yourself:

```
template <typename T, typename ...Ts>
inline constexpr bool areT_v = std::conjunction_v<std::is_same<T,Ts>...>;

static_assert( areT_v<int,int,int,int>);
static_assert(!areT_v<int,int,int,char>);
```

Answer (score 3):

Just this

```
template<typename Type, typename... T>
using areTypeT = and_<std::is_same<T, Type>...>;
```

Comment: what is `_and`?

Answer (score 2):

```
template <typename ... Types>
constexpr bool all_same_v = sizeof...(Types) ? (std::is_same_v<std::tuple_element_t<0, std::tuple<Types...>>, Types> && ...) : false;
```

Assuming that an empty pack would result in a false value.