# How to implement a type trait that checks whether all the elements of a parameter pack are of some concrete type T?

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

I want to provide a static assert that checks whether all the elements of a parameter pack are of some type T.

The client code looks like:

```
template <typename... Args>
void foo(Args... args)
{
    static_assert(are_all_of_the_type<int, Args...>::value);
}
```

Any ideas on how to implement the type trait `are_all_of_the_type`?

A very alike question was addressed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31533469/check-a-parameter-pack-for-all-of-type-t), yet I don't see how to use the proposed solution with a parameter pack.

Comment: Are you okay with just doing `(std::is_same_v<T, Args> && ...)`?

Comment: Tell me if this dupe has a problem.

Comment: @0x499602D2 `static_assert(std::is_same_v<int, Args> && ...);` doesn't compile :( (expected expression)

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot many thanks, `static_assert(std::conjunction_v<std::is_same<Args, int>...>)` works fine

Comment: You forgot the parenthesis: `static_assert((std::is_same_v<int, Args> && ...))`