# How to combine conditions from type_traits the standard way

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, type-traits

For example, I want to use type `T` only if `std::is_pointer<T>` and `std::is_const<T>` evaluate to `true_type`.

Of course, there is a simple way like this:

```
template <typename T>
void f(T t, std::true_type, std::true_type) {}
template <typename T>
void f(T t)
{
  f(t, std::is_pointer<T>{}, std::is_const<T>{});
}
```

But I want something like this:

```
template <typename T>
void f(T t, std::true_type) {}
template <typename T>
void f(T t)
{
  f(t, std::and<std::is_pointer<T>, std::is_const<T>>{});
}
```

Does the Standard Library contain something like `std::and`? If not, is there a simple way to implement it with the desired functionality?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can simply `&&` together the results of the traits and put them in a `std::integral_constant`:

```
std::integral_constant<bool, 
                       std::is_pointer<T>::value && std::is_const<T>::value>
```

---

Or you can write a generic trait `and`. Some possibilities from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29603364/type-trait-to-check-that-all-types-in-a-parameter-pack-are-copy-constructible):

**Option 1**:

```
template<typename... Conds>
  struct and_
  : std::true_type
  { };

template<typename Cond, typename... Conds>
  struct and_<Cond, Conds...>
  : std::conditional<Cond::value, and_<Conds...>, std::false_type>::type
  { };

//usage
and_<std::is_pointer<T>, std::is_const<T>>
```

**Option 2**:

```
template<bool...> struct bool_pack;
template<bool... bs> 
using and_ = std::is_same<bool_pack<bs..., true>, bool_pack<true, bs...>>;

//usage
and_<std::is_pointer<T>, std::is_const<T>>
```

---

When we get [fold expressions](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4191.html) you'll be able to do this:

```
template<typename... Args>
using and_ = std::integral_constant<bool, (Args::value && ...) >;
```

Your compiler may already support this under the `-std=c++1z` flag like [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7a11c3e300df355b).

Answer (score 8):

With the advent of C++17 [conjunction](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conjunction) and [disjunction](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/disjunction) you could easily compose for variadic (number of) predicates:

```
template <class T, template <class> class... Ps>
constexpr bool satisfies_all_v = std::conjunction<Ps<T>...>::value;

template <class T, template <class> class... Ps>
constexpr bool satisfies_any_v = std::disjunction<Ps<T>...>::value;
```

And this is how you'd use it:

```
satisfies_all_v<T, is_pointer, is_const>
```

[**Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5be6c90b26b483dc)